# how to include gif images in org-export to LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

When I export from org-mode to PDF via LaTeX, my `jpg` images export successfully, but my `gif` images do not appear. The `gif` images do export when I export to HTML.

I found a variable called `org-export-html-inline-image-extensions`, which is set to `"png" "jpeg" "jpg" "gif" "svg" "tif" "gif"`. However, I don't find an analogous variable for LaTeX.

Closest thing I could find is `org-latex-inline-image-rules`, but adding `gif` to that had no effect on export.

How do I direct org-mode to include `gif` images in export?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LaTeX doesn't like `.gif`s: it needs the image in some other form.

Nevertheless, this can be done. But there's a bit of setting up that needs doing.

1. You need [imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) available to convert `.gif` to `.png`.
2. You need to set `org` up so that it will use `pdflatex` with the `--shell-escape` enabled. This enables LaTeX to run shell programs while compiling, and is dis-enabled by default for security reasons. `(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process "pdflatex --shell-escape --batch %f")` Alternatively export to a latex file and run `pdflatex --shell-escape [filename].tex` at the command line.
3. You need to tell `ox-latex` that a `.gif` file is to be treated as an image file: `(setq org-latex-inline-image-rules '(("file" . "\\.\\(pdf\\|jpeg\\|jpg\\|png\\|ps\\|eps\\|tikz\\|pgf\\|svg\\|gif\\)\\'")))` (or customize that variable). Otherwise it will not include your file using as a graphics file but think it is a link, and just export the URL.
4. You need to add these magical incantations (or some suitable variation) to your latex header -- they depend on the `graphicx` package, but that is included by default anyway.

   ```
   #+LATEX_HEADER: \DeclareGraphicsRule{.gif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `basename #1 .gif`-gif-converted-to.png}
   #+LATEX_HEADER: \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.gif}
   ```

The key one is the first. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4982/5404 for a much fuller explanation. The format I have given is assuming that your `.gif` files are in the same directory as your `.org` (or, strictly, as the `.tex` file it produces). If that isn't the case, you will need to do some more fiddling to make sure TeX can find the files. The answer I linked includes an example.

What this command does is use the `--shell-escape` to call out to `imagemagick`, converting `foo.gif` to `foo-gif-converted-to.png` i.e. effectively it converts the files on the fly. You end up of course with a load of `.png` files. Still, it means you can keep your `gif` for HTML export, so something is achieved I suppose.

Comment: But wouldn't you just get the same result if you'd just manually `convert` the gif into a png? And what about animated gif's? I off googling trying to find a way to include an animation into my beamer presentation. But thanks for the starting point